# Binding width of Gridview to width of ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight-4.0, binding, width, scrollviewer, radgridview

I have a project that in which I have a RadGridView inside of a Scrollviewer.  I've been trying to bind the width of the RadGridView to the width of the ScrollViewer.  The ScrollViewer's width is set to Auto so that it will expand to fit the size of it's containing object, but when I bind the width of the RadGridView to the ScrollViewer it only expands to fit the information inside of the RadGridView instead of filling the remaining space of the ScrollViewer.  What I would like is for the RadGridView to expand to auto fit the ScrollViewer, which also expands automatically to fit the parent object.  However I haven't been able to find a workable solution for this problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to bind the width of the RadGridView to the ScrollViewer, just don't set the size of the RadGridView, like the following,

```
    <ScrollViewer Margin="60" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hey @Xin, thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately this does not solve my problem, it still only shows the two existing rows inside of the RadGridView.  Perhaps I should explain more thoroughly. In my ScrollViewer I have a StackPanel, which has a DataForm above a Grid which has a RadGridView and a DataPager. The HorizontalScrollBar is disabled in order to disable left/right scrolling, but it won't expand to fit the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Hey @Xin, thanks for the reply.  Fortunately I figured it out.  I had the ScrollViewer set to Left Aligned, I erased that and now it expands.